# VLOKUP returns a wrong range

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I have an excel data sheet like this:

[image]

I calculated the **Assigned breakdown per week** column using

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,table1,2,TRUE)
```

My problem is, it assigned 3 for the random number 0.75. But it should be 4 as I know.

Following is my column and row details.

1. Columns:- C,D,E,F
2. table1:- E2:F7 (Interval lower bound and Breakdown per week)
3. Assigned breakdown 1st data row:- 2(C2)

Why am I getting a wrong value for 0.75?

Comment: because most likely the numbers have more decimals than what is shown.  formulas ignore the format and look at the stored number(what shows in the formula bar).

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah the original number shows like 0.745493040741341 for 0.75.

Comment: Does that mean I should not format it? or is there any other way to overcome this even the formatting changed?

Comment: Round the numbers.

Comment: As @ScottCraner suggested, something like `=VLOOKUP(ROUND(D2,2),table1,2,TRUE)` should work.